# Required request part 'image' is not present with React and Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I am getting "`MissingServletRequestPartException`: Required request part 'studentImg' is not present", It works fine with Postman but not with `React`. I am trying to call a end point in a `Spring boot` restful API.

Backend Controller Code:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<StudentFile> addStudentImg(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("studentImg") MultipartFile studentImg) {
    boolean isStudent = (Boolean) request.getAttribute("isStudent");
    if(false == isStudent) {
        throw new EtAuthException("Only Student can add their image.");
    } else {
        Long addedBy = (Long) request.getAttribute("studentId");
        StudentFile studentFile = studentFileService.addStudentImg(studentImg, addedBy);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentFile, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }   
}
```

React Components' Code Snippets:

```
handleStudentImgChange(event) {
      this.setState({ studentImg: event.target.files[0] });
  }  

handleOnSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { studentImg } = this.state;
    this.props.addStudentImg(studentImg);
    this.setState({ studentImg: null });
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addStudentImg: (studentImg) => {
      dispatch(addStudentImgAction(studentImg));
    },
  };

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddStudentImgPage);
```

React Axios Call:

```
import axios from "axios";

const token = "...";
export const addStudentImg = (studentImg) => {
  let bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append("studentImg", studentImg[0]);
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    // Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  };
  return axios
    .request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/api/studentfiles/add/",
      data: bodyFormData,
      headers: headers,
    })
    .then((res) => res.data);
};
```

The network log:   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4a5c.png)   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQZV1.png)

I'm unable to find any solution regarding that. Please give suggestions.
*Thanks in Advance* :D

Comment: can you add, how your network log looks like for this request?

Comment: @IleshPatel I've added the network log {headers, payload}, let me know if you need anything else...
Also `prescriptionImg == studentImg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I changed these lines:

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append("studentImg", studentImg[0]);
```

With these:

```
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
const blob = new Blob([studentImg], {type: studentImg.type});
bodyFormData.append("studentImg", blob);
```

When I logged `studentImg` just above the `bodyFormData`, I get the response something like: `{type: 'ADD_STUDENT_IMG', studentImg: File}` where it was json object like this: [image: fig]

Then, I put thse lines and these are just working fine with it.

```
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
const blob = new Blob([studentImg.studentImg], {
  type: studentImg.studentImg.type,
});
bodyFormData.append("studentImg", blob);
```

To understand how these lines are working:
Please read the `FormData` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and also some additional information about how it's serialized over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#using_formdata_objects).

If any queries, please ask. (P.S. `prescriptionImg == studentImg` *for fig.*)
*Thanks :D*

Answer (score 1):

You already set files[0] when you set

```
handleStudentImgChange(event) {
      this.setState({ studentImg: event.target.files[0] });
  }
```

then again, you are trying to access

```
bodyFormData.append("studentImg", studentImg[0]);
```

This, seems wrong, change this to

```
bodyFormData.append("studentImg", studentImg);
```

and see if it works..

Comment: It's not working after removing it too.